# Psychopy: How to display Japanese?

Tags: python, psychopy

I am want to display some Japanese sentences on Pyschopy through coding and I used code like this:

```
from Psychopy import visual,core

win=visual.Window([400,400])

message=visual.TextStim(win,text='先生を呼んだ学生')

message=setAutoDraw(True)

win.flip()
```

and the response is that "`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe5' in file D:\用户目录\我的文档\untitled.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`".

I guess it's illegal to use TextStim to present Japanese, but I see in the builder view it's ok to do so. So I wonder if there's some way for me to display Japanese by coding?

Comment: It seems you’re using Python 2; upgrade to Python 3, and text handling will be much nicer.

Comment: Did you try actually reading that article?

Comment: You mean the article on "http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ ".? I read it and am now trying to declare a coding name for Janpanese.And I also tracked the scripts for the builderview and found this:        #!/usr/bin/envpython2                                                                            #-*-coding:utf-8-*       I tried to use this in my code ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Heaven, I figured that you might have incorporated Michael's response in your next question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275119/psychopyis-it-possible-to-display-2-words-in-different-colors-within-the-same-f. Please mark Michael's response as answering your question if it did in fact help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PsychoPy is going to add beta support for Python 3 shortly, which will improve unicode handling, but for the timebeing, you should be able to run this even under the current Python 2.7. This tweak to your code works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from psychopy import visual,core

win=visual.Window([400,400])

message = visual.TextStim(win, text = u'先生を呼んだ学生')

message.draw()

win.flip()

core.wait(5)
```

i.e. explicitly declare the utf-8 encoding in the header but also precede your string literal with `u` to indicate that it is a unicode string (this step eventually won't be necessary under Python 3 I think).