# Psychopy:Is it possible to display 2 words in different colors within the same frame?

Tags: python, psychopy

I want to display a sentence with words in different colors within the same frame . But all the code I've seen just change the color of the stimuli as a whole , not  a part of it ...
Here's my code for a try ,but it failed

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from psychopy import visual,core 
win = visual.Window([400,400])
sent=[u'先生',u'を呼んだ',u'学生が',u'教室に',u'入った。']
sent[0].color=[1,1,1]
sent[1].color=[1.0,-1,-1]
sentence=visual.TextStim(win,text=sent[0]+sent[1])
sentence.setAutoDraw(True)
win.flip()
```

I am wondering whether there's a way for me to change the text color before it becomes a visual.TextStim ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the `TextStim` applies formatting (colour, italic, etc) to its entire contents. If you want words with different colours, they unfortunately each need to be in their own `TextStim`

An alternative is to the use `TextBox` class which I think allows per-character formatting, but only for monospace fonts: 
http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/textbox.html#psychopy.visual.TextBox

Having said that, I've found it doesn't work reliably at present, at least on Mac OS.